# How do I enlarge the type on my site page at Mi Yodeya?

Tags: support, font

For some reason, the size of my type has shrunken at Mi Yodeya. How do I enlarge it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a comment by Monica Cellio amplifying a comment from msh210:

> Control (or command) 0 resets to the default, and from there you can use + or - to get to the size you want. I find that this approach can get me past weird states more quickly than trying to figure out what went wrong.